# Calculation real time based on 3 dropdown value plus hard coded value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I managed to set default value using JS as below:

```
function myFunction() {
    var apple   = 777777; document.getElementById("Apple").value = apple;}
```

and called on my Dropdown using

```
<select class="element select medium" id="ProductOrigin" name="ProductOrigin" onchange="myFunction()">
```

As I have 10 values needs to created I created 10 var and set 10 times, they are may be better way.

Also the calulation works but not on real time I need click on **TAB** or using mouse to click on each item so it calculated it after that event is there any way we can real time calculation or instant calculation.

I tried using `onchange(), keyup()` as the calculation done on the input text:

```
<div>
  <label class="description" for="Apple">Apple</label>
  <input id="Apple" name="Apple" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" readonly="true"/>
</div>
```

Is any way to handle the event once drop (any of 3 dropdown) it do instant calculation.

**working Codepen not that fast or best way may be** 
[calculation based on look up and 10 hard coded value](https://codepen.io/dunya/pen/ywvEeg)

https://codepen.io/dunya/pen/ywvEeg

I dont know how to handle it or improve it.

Can you please help?

Many thanks.

Comment: Try `onblur` event

Comment: thanks, any example please.

Comment: lots of issues here. Why loading the Products  on change of selects? Why not pre-populate them on load? The calculation result can be different if Volume drop-down is changed. So you should have one function calculate() which will calculate for all items based on volume and item's current value. Trigger this function on change of volume and on keyup of every item.

Comment: @NawedKhan thanks, could you please help me on pointing my issues if you can with details please."lots of issues here. Why loading the Products on change of selects? Why not pre-populate them on load?2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code with following changes:

- Values assigned to items on load
- Removed trggiers from fields and replaced with event handlers in javascript
- All items are calculated because what is the use of having onchange, keyup or blur on a text field that is readonly?

And [here is the update and working codepen.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZLzxB)

```
function myLoad() {
                var apple   = 777777;
                var apricot   = 111111  ;
                var banana   = 222222  ;
                var bilberry   = 3333 ;
                var blackberry   = 3333  ;
                var blackcurrant   = 2222 ;
                var blueberry   = 88888 ;
                var boysenberry   = 8888888 ;
                var cherry   = 99999 ;
                var coconut = 99887 ;
            $("#Apple").value = apple;
            $("#Apricot").value = apricot;
            $("#Banana").value = banana;
            $("#Bilberry").value = bilberry;
            $("#Blackberry").value = blackberry;
            $("#Blackcurrant").value = blackcurrant;
            $("#Blueberry").value = blueberry;
            $("#Boysenberry").value = boysenberry;
            $("#Cherry").value = cherry;
            $("#Coconut").value = coconut;
        }

function myCalculate(){
      var volume = $("#Volume").val();
      var productOrigin = $("#ProductOrigin").val();
      var geographicalLocation = $("#GeoLocation").val();

      if (volume === "" || productOrigin === "") {
            // alert("Please select the product origin and volume.");
            return;
        }

      var tableToUse = geographicalLocation === "" ? productOrigin : geographicalLocation;

      $("input[type='text']").each(function(i){
       // Current product ID, e.g. "Apple", "Apricot", etc.
       var currentProductId = $(this).attr('id');

       // Amount to multiply.
       var multiplier = $(`table#${tableToUse} tbody > tr[product='${currentProductId}'] > td[volume='${volume}']`).text();

       // A <span> element, to be populated with the calculated product volume.
       var result = $("<span name='result'>");

       // Calculate the figure and update the result element.
       result.text($(this).val() * multiplier); 

       // Remove any previously added <span> result elements.
       $(this).next("span").remove();

       // Insert result after the current input field.
       $(this).after(result);

      }); 

    }

myLoad();

        $('.select').on('change', myCalculate);
        $("input[type='text']").on('keyup', myCalculate);
```